# Margin-top issue, not moving the specific div but the div it's placed in

Tags: css, html, margin

I have an issue with the margin-top property in CSS. I want to have an image inside a div, that's inside another div to have a 20px top margin. I tried the following:

[Css code]

```
* {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

div.wipbox {
margin-top: 20px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I excluded the styling of all the other objects, unnecessary in this context.

[Html code]

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pagestyle.css">
</head>


<body>
<!-- "mainbox" is the box where "wipbox" is placed in -->
<div class="mainbox">
    <div class="wipbox">
        <img src="workinprogress.jpg" width="200" height="200">

        </img>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="buttonlink" href="http://www.ysbakker.eu/beta">
    <div class="buttonbox">
            <p class="betatext">
                Click for beta      
            </p>
    </div>
</a>

</body>

</html>
```

So, whenever I try to set the margin-top property to 20px, it won't show. I also found out that it will for some reason set the margin-top property of the div "mainbox". Anyone knows what to do?
My website is [here](http://www.ysbakker.eu/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a [collapsing margin(s) issue](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> [**Box model - 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

In this instance, you could add `overflow:hidden` to the parent `div` element in order to fix it:

This ***will work***.. I tested it in the dev tool.

```
div.mainbox {
    overflow:hidden;       /* Added */
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 0px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
    transition: background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, this one answered my question! It now works as I wanted. Just wondering, what does overflow: hidden do? thanks!

Comment: @YSbakker It establishes a new block formatting context. Here are the relevant specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour, something to do with margin collapsing.

To "fix", try using `padding-top` on the container, rather than `margin-top` on the content.

Alternatively, you can add `padding:0.01px` to any element to prevent margin collapsing in it.

Comment: This one worked as well, only thing is, the maibox will also stretch out 20px. The overflow:hidden method works better for me! Thanks anyways :)